# Open all selected files as hidden buffer?

Tags: ctrlp

Is there a way Ctrl-P can open all selected files as hidden buffer?
This is how I tried to load files into my buffer:

```
<c-p>               (opens Ctrl-P in file mode)
<c-o>               
a                   (marks all files in the match window)
i
```

The last "i" was intended to open the selected files as hidden buffers.
Instead "i" appeared in the search dialog.

From :help CtrlP

```
Opening multiple files:

  <c-z>
    - Mark/unmark a file to be opened with <c-o>.
    - Mark/unmark a file to create a new file in its directory using <c-y>.

  <c-o>
    - Open files marked by <c-z>.
    - When no file has been marked by <c-z>, open a console dialog with the
      following options:

      Open the selected file:
        t - in a tab page.
        v - in a vertical split.
        h - in a horizontal split.
        r - in the current window.
        i - as a hidden buffer.
        x - (optional) with the function defined in |g:ctrlp_open_func|.

      Other options (not shown):
        a - mark all files in the match window.
        d - change CtrlP's local working directory to the selected file's
            directory and switch to find file mode.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to open all selected files as hidden buffer.

Add this line to vimrc:

```
let g:ctrlp_open_multiple_files = 'ij'
```

where

```
i - all files as hidden buffers.
j - after opening, jump to the first opened tab or window.
```

In Vim:

```
<c-p>               open Ctrl-P in file mode
<c-o>               open a console dialog
a                   mark all files in the match window
<c-z>               mark/unmark a file
<c-o>               open marked files as hidden buffers
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
" 1r - open the first file in the current window, and remaining opened as hidden buffers.
let g:ctrlp_open_multiple_files = '1r'
```